# OpenERP 6.1 No handler found

Tags: odoo

I have been running OpenERP 6.1 on Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS for the last 3 or 4 months. During that time I restarted (rebooted) Ubuntu several times. I installed OpenERP from a downloaded package from their web site. I manually added the pychart.py module as it wouldn't start openerp-server without it. Everything was running smoothly until now.

Today I replaced the procurement.pyc file with a modified recompiled version and backed up the original version under a different name.
I then restarted openerp-server (sudo service openerp restart).
I connected to openerp from my Firefox windows client, and got a "No handler found" white screen.

Before all that manipulation it was working fine. So I thought I'd stuffed it up with my change and decided to revert back the original procurement.pyc file.
Restarted openerp-server following the same procedure as above but still got the "No handler found" white screen.

Rebooted Ubuntu, restarted openerp-server from the services and manually numerous times, refreshed the firefox connection, added the port 8069/tcp OUT to UFW as it was only IN. Nothing helped, I still get the "No handler found" white screen.

How is that possible???

I read other identical issues on the net from other people, but every time they seem to have found their own resolution.

The only thing I rely on is the log file:

```
2013-01-07 14:10:03,958 1381 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 6.1-20121008-233119

2013-01-07 14:10:03,958 1381 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /home/download/openerp- 6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons

2013-01-07 14:10:03,958 1381 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2013-01-07 14:10:03,958 1381 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2013-01-07 14:10:03,959 1381 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp
2013-01-07 14:10:03,959 1381 INFO ? openerp.service.netrpc_server: starting NET-RPC service on 0.0.0.0:8070
2013-01-07 14:10:03,960 1381 INFO ? openerp.netsvc: Starting 1 services
2013-01-07 14:10:03,986 1381 INFO ? openerp.wsgi.core: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2013-01-07 14:10:04,062 1381 INFO ? openerp.addons.web: embedded mode
2013-01-07 14:10:04,226 1381 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2013-01-07 14:10:04,227 1381 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named sale_order
2013-01-07 14:10:04,227 1381 ERROR ? openerp: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-6.1_20121008_233119-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/openerp-server", line 252, in <module>
    openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-6.1_20121008_233119-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 419, in load_openerp_module
    getattr(sys.modules['openerp.addons.' + module_name], info['post_load'])()
  File "/home/download/openerp-6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons/web/__init__.py", line 29, in wsgi_postload
    app = common.http.Root(o)
  File "/home/download/openerp-6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 453, in __init__
    static_dirs = self._load_addons(openerp_addons_namespace)
  File "/home/download/openerp-6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 523, in _load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-6.1_20121008_233119-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 139, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/home/download/openerp-6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons/sale/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import report
  File "/home/download/openerp-6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons/sale/report/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sale_order
ImportError: No module named sale_order
2013-01-07 14:10:04,228 1381 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
2013-01-07 14:10:28,283 1381 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.xxx.xx.xx - - [07/Jan/2013 14:10:28] "GET /web/webclient/home HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2013-01-07 14:10:37,390 1381 INFO ? openerp.netsvc: Stopping 1 services
```

For clarification purpose, the IP address 192.xxx.xx.xx corresponds to the client trying to access openerp over the network and receiving the "No handler found" message. A try on another client has had the same result.

Why the two CRITICAL lines? And why couldn't it load module Web when it wasn't a problem an hour before? It tells me the sale_order module doesn't exists but it does.

Some resolution says to add the path to the addons folder into the openerp-server.init file. But why would I do this when it didn't ask for it an hour before? Also it is mentioning an openerp-web project, which apparently turns into an openerp-web folder under addons once installed, and should be specified into the addons path. I currently do not have this folder and never needed it before, so I don't believe I am on the right path to solve my problem here.

Has anyone got any idea? This makes absolutely no sense to me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which package did you use, exactly? How did you install it?

Comment: I believe the package was openerp_6.1-latest-1_all.deb

Comment: sudo wget http://nightly.openerp.com/6.1/releases/openerp_6.1-latest-1_all.deb.   And then I followed mostly the method indicated here: http://elkafil.blogspot.fr/2012/05/installer-openerp-611-sur-ubuntu-1204.html.  And finally the manual install of pychart.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in the sale module,in the report folder is there a file named sale_order.py?
If not please download the sale module and replace with your sale module. sale_order.py have parser for sale order report. If you dont want the report please comment the line import sale_order from the **init**.py file in the report folder of sale module.

Comment: Ok, what happened is that I involuntarily deleted the sale_order.py and pyc files. I recompiled a pyc file and re-imported into the sale/report directory and it has fixed my problem. Thank you for putting me on the path to finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in standard modules, there is no module named sale_order. Perhaps sale module. Check dependencies in your customized module.

Comment: That's the thing I don't get, I have removed my customized module and reverted back to the original one, that is "procurement.pyc", which the sales module depend on. I might have stuffed the procurement.pyc filename when moving it back. I will check tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's something other than the Debian package installed, and the two are interacting in Bad Ways. Look at the paths in the traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-6.1_20121008_233119-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/openerp-server", line 252, in <module>
```

compared to this one:

```
File "/home/download/openerp-6.1-20121008-233119/openerp/addons/sale/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
```

This is most definately not from an installed Debian package, and in any case it's weird that you have bits of OpenERP in such different places. Is this expected in your environment? If not, I bet this is the problem.

Comment: It is a bit unusual but it works fine and is interacting nicely. My problem came from deleting the sale_order.py and pyc files.